# Is Javascript the only choice for DOM interaction when embedding a web browser?

Tags: javascript, dom, xulrunner, chromium-embedded

I've looked at the various ways to embed a web browser into an application (like IE or Safari via OS-specific means, or Firefox/Mozilla via XULRunner, or Chrome via the Chromium Embedded Framework) and I've managed to integrate CEF with my app up to a point where I'm convinced that it'll all work as expected.  Now, it seems to me that whenever I want to modify the DOM (e.g. to add or remove elements), I'll have to do this via Javascript, i.e. my application calls out to Javascript where the actual work is done.

I wonder why this is so.  My (naive?) belief is that if for example I call `appendChild` in Javascript, the actual "work" of appending a child will eventually be performed by a C/C++ function as the browser itself is written in C/C++ and not in Javascript.  So, I'm wondering why in an embedded web browser I can't call this C/C++ function directly instead of going through Javascript.  I understand that for general scripting you don't want other languages than Javascript for security reasons, but if the browser is embedded into an application I can control anyway this shouldn't be the reason, should it?

What am I missing?

Comment: In IE for example you can write code in a BHO that interacts with the DOM with C++ and C# and any other .net language. In Chrome you can use C and C++ with the [Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client). Don't expect either of these to be faster - the DOM is pretty fast in JavaScript after all and there are libraries that maintain a virtual dom and do updates in bulks very fast like React.

Comment: What do you aim to gain by doing so?

Comment: Do you really think, that studying C++ source code of each browser, reading specification and calling functions (which are different in each browser an may change in each version of browser) would be easier, than calling JS, which is the same for all browsers? It is like when you want to buy stuff in shop, and your house is behind the shop, so instead of going around the shop you want owner to let you climb through the window.

Comment: @IvanKuckir: The **DOM** is a language-agnostic standard. Have a look at [this Java package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CEF is implemented as a layer between chromium's [content api](https://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module/content-api) and your application. When using CEF, Chromium is a library inside CEF, and you only have access to CEF's Public API, which is more or less restricted to whatever chromium content api leverages (keep in mind no browser was created as an embeddable plugin and then evolved into an application, it was always the other way around). The content API was the way google engineers had to formalize some forms of introspection, but they aren't completed simply because the browser isn't completely modular by itself. There's work in progress on chromium code to separate specific "do-it-all" components in more general ones that you may pick at will.

Therefore you can't simply hook into chromium's implementation details when using CEF: you'd need to patch it to implement something it doesn't expose by itself. CEF implements a class for DOM traversal (see [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/%28default%29/CefDOMDocument.html)), but you can only pick at DOM, not change it.

That said, on the C++ side you can do some arbitrary stuff such as inspecting/mangling http requests (which allows you to inject javascript into pages, for instance), and running arbitrary javascript code straight from C++, which can, by it's own turn, asynchronously call back to C++ code by diverse paths (ajax -> http handling in C++, or V8 extensions which you can code straightly in C++.

See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration for more details.

One could customize CEF or go straightly to chromium source code, but that thing is huge. Other solutions I heard of are more or less alike in terms of API limitations, i.e. [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/), [Mozilla's Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko/Embedding_Mozilla), etc.